# return Json prompts me to download Json instead of giving it to the controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I don't understand why this keeps happening... An hour ago I had the return value of my action returning the Json Data to my view and It was updating my ListBox just fine... I don't know what on earth happened... but all of a sudden it is just prompting me to download the data... I have know Idea what I did, I didn't do anything as a matter of fact... I must have did something though, because it is no longer working!!! very frustrating...

Here is my view and Jquery function...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchByDemographic1(FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        SLI.Text = patient.name[0].lastName + ", " + patient.name[0].firstName + " | " + patient.address[0].street1 + " | " + patient.address[0].city + " | " + patient.address[0].country;
                SLI.Value = patient.compositeID[0].id + "";
                patientList.Add(SLI);
        }
        ViewData["PatientListToAdd"] = patientList;
        //ViewData["POPID"] = PopID;

        return Json(patientList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
    }



    $(function () {
    $("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#DemoGraphID");
        var srlzdform = form.serialize();
        var PopID = <% =PopID %>
        var options = [];
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        $.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", formCollection:srlzdform, function (data) {
            options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're right, a JsonResult is a type of ActionResult, but last time I had this problem I thought that was what I had changed. If you don't get an answer, I'll go look again.

Comment: The funny thing is it was WORKING like an hour ago...  This is very frustrating... I swear it was working... I have no idea what happened.

Comment: clear your cache and set the response.ContentType to "text/javascript"

Comment: @ilia choly
Total-Idiot-questions how do I clear my cache... And where do I change my response.ContentType?  Figured out the first one... How do I change my response.ContextType in the .Post method

Comment: Depends on your browser, google it. I don't know asp, but the problem is that it's sending the wrong `ContentType:` http response header. You can check it in firebug. That's why I didn't post an anwer.

Comment: Does anybody know how to change the response.ContextType?  I am lost?

Comment: Never mind.  Figured that out.  Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an error in you JavaScript (check FireBug) that is causing your `click` event to fail, submitting the form normally (and returning a JSON response, not calling your callback function).

Change this:

```
$.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", formCollection:srlzdform, function (data) {
    options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
        return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
    });
    $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
});
```

To this:

```
$.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", srlzdform, function (data) {
    options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
        return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
    });
    $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
});
```

The offending code is `formCollection:srlzdform`. This is not a valid JavaScript expression and will cause an error. You may have meant `{ formCollection:srlzdform }`, but I don't *think* that's necessary. The model binder should be able able to figure it out.

Comment: I should Kill myself for being so stupid!  Just kidding I am not suicidal... Can I by you a beer?  I can't believe I didn't see it before.  I should have figure it out when my other javascript functions weren't working...  Man I feel like a complete idiot... I must have waisted 3 hours looking at this.  Thank you, thank you, thank you :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @DmainEvent: Haha, no big deal! Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes `:)`